# Accessing an action by tag in Cocos2D

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I have an action that I declared in the -init method.

```
  -(id) init
{
        if( (self=[super init])) {
            sprite = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"Icon@2x.png"];
            sprite.position = ccp(150,150);
            [self addChild:sprite];
            sprite.tag = 13;
            self.isTouchEnabled = YES;

            CCAction *anAction = [CCBlink actionWithDuration:5 blinks:10];
            anAction.tag = 15;
    }
    return self;
}
```

Now, I can access the sprite without any problems.

```
-(void)ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

CCNode *node = [self getChildByTag:13];
NSAssert([node isKindOfClass:[CCSprite class]],@"is NOT member of CCSprite");
CCSprite *sprite = (CCSprite *)node;
sprite.scale = CCRANDOM_0_1();
```

}

Now I don't know how to access my action via tag.. would anyone mind showing me a small example ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code assignes a new action to an automatic variable and doesn't run it. `anAction` is not retained by anyone, so it gets autoreleased:

```
    ...
    CCAction *anAction = [CCBlink actionWithDuration:5 blinks:10];
    anAction.tag = 15;
}
```

If you schedule your action with `[self runAction:anAction]`, you can access it by `[sprite getActionByTag:15]`. But if you want to create an action without running it, you should save your action in your class property and access it by casting a node to your class.